# scaling font size in single equation

Tags: equations, fontsize

I am dealing with the proofs of my academic paper, which is dealt with by some company who use LaTeX **only** for setting each equation individually. In order to adapt the font size in an equation (let's not discuss here why) I could use commands like `\small`, i.e.

```
\small
\begin{eqnarray*}
    a=b.
\end{eqnarray*}
```

but is there a way to scale the fontsize to an arbitrary size? Note that I cannot use any packages, but standard LaTeX commands work. There must be a way, since I have seen it done in a the proofs of another paper, but cannot remember how. (Internet searches only bring up solutions with commands like `\small` or some LaTeX package.)

I attempted

```
\scalebox{0.98}{
\begin{eqnarray*}
    a=b.
\end{eqnarray*}
}
```

but got `missing \endgroup` (from the LaTeX interface used for proof editing).

Comment: Doesn't `\fontsize` work for you?

Comment: @JasperHabicht sorry I was thinking about `\DeclareMathSizes` but confused myself, arbitrary sizes still work here, as you say.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Indeed. I had figured this out meanwhile -- only shows that I was to eager to ask here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Jasper's comment, you could try:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
    a=b.
\end{eqnarray*}
\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont
\begin{eqnarray*}
    a=b.
\end{eqnarray*}
\fontsize{7pt}{7pt}\selectfont
\begin{eqnarray*}
    a=b.
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to say that what the two numbers mean that `\fontsize` accepts as its arguments and that they can be any floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

`\scalebox` is like `\mbox` so only allows horizontal mode constructs.

so

```
\scalebox{0.98}{$\displaymode a=b$}
```

would work, but to use a multiline display you need to nest a `\parbox`

```
\scalebox{0.98}{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
\begin{align*}
a&=b\\
1&=2
\end{align*}}}
```